# Add New Run Script Action for 300+ schemes in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an Xcode project which has over 300 schemes/targets and I have a custom script that I need to run before the app starts building. I've figured out how to do this by editing desired scheme, select Build->Pre-actions->New Run Script Action->Provide Build Settings From  and then pasting this script (which dynamically changes version info and bundle id in my notification extension's plist file):

```
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "${PROJECT_DIR}/$INFOPLIST_FILE")
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "${SRCROOT}/NotificationService/Info.plist"

buildVersion=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleShortVersionString" "${PROJECT_DIR}/$INFOPLIST_FILE")
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString $buildVersion" "${SRCROOT}/NotificationService/Info.plist"

buildID=${PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER}
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleIdentifier $buildID.NotificationService" "${SRCROOT}/NotificationService/Info.plist"
```

The issue is I have to do this for over 300 of my schemes and is a tedious timely effort. Is there some way to apply this to all of my schemes/targets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up solving issue by creating a fastlane script which basically adds this pre-action run script inside each of the xcscheme files in the appropriate spot in the XML.